# Не работает css для тега <a>

Tags: css, bootstrap, href

Я пытаюсь убрать подчеркивания у ссылок, но css работает только, если убрать строку с подключением bootstrap (ссылка: 
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color: white; 
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: white; 
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Почему так происходит? Мне нужен bootstrap и нужно убрать подчеркивание ссылок, как быть?

Вот пример с кодом для наглядности: https://codepen.io/letsdoit/pen/XzJBqN?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас стили bootstrap перебивают ваши.
Подключите bootstrap в codepen через настройки CSS --> Add External CSS или добавьте !important к стилям.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Буду знать теперь.